# How to send userid and password from android to a ASP page

Tags: java, android, asp-classic, send

I am trying to create an android app for my uni's portal. Amazingly how Macquarie Uni doesnt have one.
I have created a simple login UI, a student/staff id textbox field and a password field, for now. and a "log in" button

I know how i can retrieve the text from the two text field but how do i send the user id and password to the asp server page and retrieve the next page in retrieve and display it.

the page is https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp

i am using http post to send the login cred.

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
HttpPost post = new HttpPost("https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp");
```

the AVD crashes every time it try to execute this command

```
HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
```

note: this is in a try/catch() block.

I am not sure why its crashing there every time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send [HttpPost](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpPost.html) to https://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp?Summit=OK.

You can discover which parameters to send by :
- Open your website with google chrome
- Press F12
- Choose "Network"
- Don't forget to check "Preserve log uppon navigation"

Good luck!

Comment: thanks for the help, i cant seem to understand how to send the id and password with httpPost. would be able to show me

Comment: You have a billion examples if you google "Android HttpPost" : http://foobarpig.com/android-dev/http-post-example-submiting-a-simple-form.html

Comment: I have and i am stuck on a part of the code. the avd crashes every time i reach that line.
PS my question is updated to that problem now

Comment: You need to execute it not in the UI thread,use AsyncTask for example.

Comment: And you need to ask for INTERNET permission in your manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I have used AsyncTask, also added INTERNET permission in the manifest. now i have a different problem in the same problem.

i get this error: "org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au refused"

Comment: Note: the declaration of post variable:

String URL =(String)"http://portal.sibt.nsw.edu.au/Default.asp";
HttpPost post = new HttpPost(URL);

new getResponse().execute(URL);// calling Async class 

public class getResponse extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
 @Override
 protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
  try {  
   HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    
   } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) { 
    Log.d("cpexception", cpe.toString());
   } catch (IOException ioe) {
    Log.d("ioexception", ioe.toString());
   }
   return "executed";
                }

 }

Answer (score 0):

```
this is how you can send username and password and recieve the response

public class callASPX
{
        public static final String URL = "http://localhost:8080/appName/actionOrServletTobeCalled";
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        callASPXobj = new callASPX();
        String username = "username";
        String password = "password";
        obj.getOutputFromUrl(URL+"?username="+username+"&password="+password);

    }
    public String getOutputFromUrl(String url) 
    {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response;
        StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new                            InputStreamReader(response.getEntity().getContent(), "UTF-8"));
        char[] buf = new char[8000];
        int l = 0;
            while (l >= 0) 
            {
                builder.append(buf, 0, l);
                l = in.read(buf);
            }
        return builder.toString();
    }   
}
```